# comparing strings on android

Tags: java, android

I am comparing two strings and every time it triggers the else statement. At first it worked with compareTo and was fine. Now, after editing some unrelated code on this part I get a false result... the value of str I get from the server. I am confused what can be wrong in here..
On server I have echo with php:

```
  <?php case "helloServer":
         echo "hello";
   break; ?>
```

In Java:

```
//if(str.compareTo("hello") == 0) {
  if(str.equals("hello")){
      if(D)Log.d("St","yes "+str);
      return true;} 
   else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   return false;
   }
```

Comment: Why haven't you logged the value of `str` in the case where you *don't* know it?

Comment: ...Does the second piece of code even compile?  Can you describe in more detail what the problem is?

Comment: This should work. Why don't you log str before the if statement to check it?

Comment: actually with this statement I am checking if my server is ON. Now it returnes every time ELSE .. while server sends same 'hello'.

Comment: I log string before and after, in log it says 'hello' but goes to else statment... I dont ged it......

Comment: Are you sure it says hello and there is no `space` or `\n` at the end of string.Try this `if(str.trim().equals("hello"))` or `if(str.replaceAll("\n","").equals("hello"))`.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the string includes a line-break at the end? And would you mind re-formatting the code? It's pretty hard to read right now.

Comment: As RanRag said, add trim() and try. I think spaces causing some issue.

Comment: 'trim()' gave me fatal error on Main..
   `if(str.replaceAll("\n","").equals("hello"))` - returned same ELSE result.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the application in Debug mode and add a break point. Inspect the variables to see if you are getting the data as expected.

Comment: I am getting data as expected... and even in debug mode it jumpes to else statment... I am working in eclipse. May be restarting would help..

Comment: PPL you would not believe it after restarting Eclipse and running again problem is gone...